# How do I specify multiple parameters in Asp.Net MVC 5 Route attributes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using the Kendo AutoComplete client javascript widget, which sends server requests such as the following:
https://domainName/Proto2/api/Goal/Lookup?text=ABC&goalId=8b625c56-7b04-4281-936f-b88d7ca27d76&filter%5Blogic%5D=and&filter%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&filter%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Boperator%5D=contains&filter%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=Description&filter%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5BignoreCase%5D=true&_=1423833493290

The MVC server side method to receive this is:

```
[Route("api/Goal/Lookup")]
[HttpGet] // if the action name doesn't start with "Get", then we need to specify this attribute
public ICollection<IAllegroGoalContract> Lookup(Guid goalId, string text = "")
```

The problem occurs if the client sends an empty value for the text parameter (ex: text=&goalId=8b625c56-7b04-4281-936f-b88d7ca27d76).  In this case .net returns the following error.

- "System error - unable to process parameters
  (goalId,text,text.String) - invalid data detected"

I've tried various Route attribute values:

```
[Route("api/Goal/Lookup/{goalId:guid},{text?}")]
[Route("api/Goal/Lookup/{text?}")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your parameters are used as a filter, so instead of the GoalId and Text parameters to be part of the route, define a class like this:

```
public class LookupOptions 
{
   public Guid GoalId { get; set; } // change this to Guid? if the client can send a nullable goalId.

   public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

So your method signature will be :

```
    [Route("api/Goal/Lookup")]
    [HttpGet] 
    public ICollection<IAllegroGoalContract> Lookup([FromUri]LookupOptions options)
    {
      // Note that [FromUri] will allow the mapping of the querystring into LookupOptions class.
    }
```

Now, you can pass your options from the client as part of the Query string and it will be assigned to the LookupOptions parameter.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried that - didn't help the error message.  Thanks for trying Omar!! The basic problem is I'm declaring 2 parameters, with the 2nd one optional.  When a value for this 2nd parm isn't specified from the client, .net's parameter binding issues error message.

Comment: can you give more details about what did you get when you tried the above? also can you try with a tool like Fiddler or Postman to send the request to the web api ?